# Definition of the Floer cochain

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry

I’m reading Paul Seidel’s *Fukaya Categories and Picard-Lefschetz Theory* right now and I’m confused about the definition of Floer cochain group on page 109 where the floer cochain group $CF^{pr}(L_0,L_1)$ is defined as a $\mathbb{K}-$ vector space with one basis vector for each $y\in\mathscr{C}(L_0,L_1)$. Then he defines the boundary operator $$\partial(y_1)=\sum_{y_0}\text{#}\mathcal{M}_Z^*(y_0,y_1)y_0$$ and obtains the cohomology $HF^{pr}(L_0,L_1)$ of $(CF^{pr}(L_0,L_1),\partial)$. However, I can’t find a natural grading of the $\mathbb{K}-$ vector space $CF^{pr}(L_0,L_1)$and regard it as a cochain complex. Thus, I can’t understand how the boundary operator works on such a “cochain group” and how he derived the cohomology group.

I’ve read other materials like Auroux and MacDuff, where the cochain is defined as a module over the Novikov ring. Does Seidel means the same thing here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The intersection point is given a grading via the absolute Maslov index. This gives a grading to the vector space, since it defines a grading on the generators.